# How do I hand off a Catalyst request to CGI::Application?

Tags: perl, catalyst, cgi-application

I have a `CGI::Application` loop like

```
while (my $q = new CGI::Fast){                                     
  S::W::Dispatch->dispatch(args_to_new => { QUERY => $q });
  my $webapp = S::W::instance();                           

  undef $CGI::Application::INSTANCE;                               
  S::W::instance(undef);                                   
  S::clear_instance();                                          
}
```

And, in short, I'd like to make that a new Catalyst dispatch..

So I want to do something like this

```
sub oldRoot :Local {
  ...
  S::W::Dispatch->dispatch(args_to_new => { QUERY => $q });
}
```

So I need to know how to reconstruct the `$q` in Catalyst. Is this easily done? Or, how do I achive this easier?

Comment: Take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI

Comment: @simbabque — Will that work for a FastCGI app?

Comment: I have no idea @Quentin. That was just my Google fu at work. :)

Comment: I was able to get this to work. But you answered in a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a lot easier than I expected.

Simply make your controller extend `Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI`, rather than `Catalyst::Controller`

```
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI' }
```

Then wrap the whole thing like this..

```
$self->cgi_to_response($c, sub {                                    
  my $q = new CGI::Fast;                                            
  S::W::Dispatch->dispatch(args_to_new => { QUERY => $q }); 
  my $webapp = S::W::instance();                            
  undef $CGI::Application::INSTANCE;                                
  S::W::instance(undef);                                    
  S::clear_instance();                                           
} );
```

It just worked..